# How do I make the whole confirm button a link in sweetalert2 in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, sweetalert2

I have a sweetalert from https://realrashid.github.io/sweet-alert/ that I am using in my controller. My confirm button only works when you click the actual 'Yes' text as this is where the link is. If I click anywhere else on the confirm button the alert just closes. I would like the whole button to go through to the link. Thank you.

```
public function show($id) {
  $user = User::find($id);

  Alert::warning('Deleting user -<br/>are you sure?')
    ->showCancelButton($btnText = 'Cancel', $btnColor = '#dc3545')
    ->showConfirmButton($btnText = '<a href="/admin/users/'. $id .'/delete">Yes</a>', $btnColor = '#38c177')
    ->autoClose(false);

  return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that library has no API to add any actions, so, you can use dirty hack:

Add some class for your link, add class to button too:

```
Alert::warning('Deleting user -<br/>are you sure?')
    ->showCancelButton($btnText = 'Cancel', $btnColor = '#dc3545')
    ->showConfirmButton(
        $btnText = '<a class="add-padding" href="/admin/users/'. $id .'/delete">Yes</a>', // here is class for link
        $btnColor = '#38c177',
        ['className'  => 'no-padding'], // add class to button
    )->autoClose(false);
```

Set styles for that class in CSS:

```
.no-padding {padding:0 !important;}

.add-padding {
    padding: .625em 2em; # padding as you need according your styles
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Updating the button to 0 padding and updating the link with your add padding lines has worked perfectly. Thank you!